# How to reference DuckDBPyRelation from another connection?

Tags: python, duckdb

I want to create a connectionless data frame like object that I can register to the connection, as I would do that with an arrow or pandas data frame.

```py
import duckdb
conn = duckdb.connect(":memory:")

df = conn.sql("SELECT * FROM '/tmp/test.csv'")
conn.close()

conn1 = duckdb.connect(":memory:")
conn1.register("test", df)
conn1.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
```

This code doesn't work with the exception: `Connection Error: Connection has already been closed`

If I comment `conn.close()`, then it throws: `The relation you are attempting to register was not made from this connection`

If I do `df = conn.sql("SELECT * FROM lineitem").arrow()` it works because the intermediate state is in the arrow format. It materializes and doesn't depend on the connection.

Can I do something similar in the `duckdb` without materialization but just to create a lazy data frame that I can register and use in another connection?

I expected that the duckdb object is connection less and that i can register it on the another connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relations are bound to a connection, this is because relations are already partially bound, the names and types of the result have been resolved.

What you're looking for is more akin to the parsed statement, I have a branch working on exposing the ExtractStatements method from the C++ API to the Python bindings.|

That would be more along the lines of what you expect, not being reliant on any given Connection, from there you can create a Relation from the parsed statement.

Comment: I understand thank you very much for your answer. Can you pin that PR that i can follow the status? And maybe showcase here as an example of how to use it.

I would then incorporate some workaround till i dont have such a construct in the python api